# How to read xml file contents in jQuery and display in html elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Jquery.I am trying to read data from "sampleXML.xml" file and display that data in Html "li" elements. so far I have done is, I have created html file as follows:file name-"Cloudtags.html":

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script  src=Cloudtags.js></script>
    <title>Css Globe: tag clouds</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Cloudtags.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cssglobe.com/ads/blogsponsor.js"></script>

    <div id="side">
        <div class="tags">
            <ul class="cld">
                <li class="tag1" id="java"><a href="https://www.google.com">google</a></li> 
                <li class="tag2"><a href="#">Chiessy</a></li>
                <li class="tag3"><a href="#">sitemap</a></li>
                <li class="tag2"><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                <li class="tag4" ><a href="#">Gohome</a></li>
                <li class="tag1"id="temp"><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
                <li class="tag1"><a href="#">It Jobz</a></li>
                <li class="tag5"><a href="#">Alza</a></li>
                <li class="tag2"><a href="#">Sea food</a></li>
                <li class="tag1"><a href="#">Hospital</a></li>
                <li class="tag3"><a href="#">Smart phone</a></li>
                <li class="tag4"><a href="#">Pizza </a></li>
                <li class="tag1"><a href="#">Aerobics</a></li>
                <li class="tag5"><a href="#">Yahoo...</a></li>
                <li class="tag1"><a href="#">Anti-Virus</a></li>
                <li class="tag2"><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="xmldata"></div>
    
</div><br>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var nm;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET" ,
        url: "sampleXML.xml" ,
        dataType: "xml" ,
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('person').each(function() {
                nm= $(this).text()
                $("#temp").html(nm);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<doc>
  <person>
    <name>sachin</name>
    <age>21</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Akash</name>
    <age>18</age>
  </person>
</doc>
```

But this does not work. Do I need to link some external file for "$.ajax". Where is my mistake?

Comment: the simple way is to create one file and then convert your xml to json then retrieve that json in ajax response. take a look at my answer given below.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Can you pull the file?  Can you parse the file?  Also you seem to be missing a semicolon.

Comment: Line after adding in temp div should be
            });

Answer (score 30):

I think you want like this, **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mVtCD/)**

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ); 

var $xml = $(xmlDoc);

var $person = $xml.find("person");

$person.each(function(){

    var name = $(this).find('name').text(),
        age = $(this).find('age').text();

    $("#ProfileList" ).append('<li>' +name+ ' - ' +age+ '</li>');

});
```

Answer (score 19):

Simply you can read XML file as dataType: "xml", it will retuen xml object already parsed. you can use it as jquery object and find anything or loop throw it…etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET" ,
    url: "sampleXML.xml" ,
    dataType: "xml" ,
    success: function(xml) {

    //var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );   <------------------this line
    //if single item
    var person = $(xml).find('person').text();  

    //but if it's multible items then loop
    $(xml).find('person').each(function(){
     $("#temp").append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');  
    }); 
    }       
});
});
```

[jQuery docs for parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Comment: Thanx @ChrisC,But still it does non working i just want to display the values "sachin"and "21" .So please can u suggest more correction.

Comment: you should use $(xml) directly without parse because it's already xml object type

Answer (score 1):

First of all create on file and then convert your xml data in array and retrieve that data in json format for ajax success response.

**Try as below:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sample.php",            
        success: function (response) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
            for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
                // here you can add html through loop
            }                
        }
    });
});
```

**sample.php**

```
$xml = "YOUR XML FILE PATH";
$json = json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($xml)),1);
echo $json;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.each()`

Suppose your `xml` is

```
<Cloudtags><id>1</id></Cloudtags><Cloudtags><id>2</id></Cloudtags><Cloudtags><id>3</id></Cloudtags>
```

In your `Ajax` `success`

```
success: function (xml) {
    $(xml).find('Cloudtags').each(function(){// your outer tag of xml
         var id = $(this).find("id").text(); // 
    });
}
```

For your case

```
success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('person').each(function(){// your outer tag of xml
             var name = $(this).find("name").text(); // 
             var age = $(this).find("age").text();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

responseText is what you are looking for. Example:

```
    $.ajax({
...
complete: function(xhr, status) {
alert(xhr.responseText);
}
});
```

Where xml is your file. Remember this will be your xml in the form form of a string. You can parse it using xmlparse as some of them mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 $.get("/folder_name/filename.xml", function (xml) {
 var xmlInnerhtml = xml.documentElement.innerHTML;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the XML using Ajax call, find the main element, loop through all the element and append data in table.

Sample code

```
 //ajax call to load XML and parse it
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dmsxwwfb5/raw/upload/v1591716537/book.xml',           // The file path.
            dataType: 'xml',    
            success: function(xml) {
               //find all book tags, loop them and append to table body
                $(xml).find('book').each(function() {
                    
                    // Append new data to the tbody element.
                    $('#tableBody').append(
                        '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' +
                                $(this).find('author').text() + '</td> ' +
                            '<td>' +
                                $(this).find('title').text() + '</td> ' +
                            '<td>' +
                                $(this).find('genre').text() + '</td> ' +
                                '<td>' +
                                $(this).find('price').text() + '</td> ' +
                                '<td>' +
                                $(this).find('description').text() + '</td> ' +
                        '</tr>');
                });
            }
        });
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/pn9xs8hf/2/

Source: [Read XML using jQuery & load it in HTML Table](https://qawithexperts.com/article/jquery/read-xml-using-jquery-load-it-in-html-table/290)