# search tag value in xml file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an xml file and I want to search some values from that file how can I do this using jquery

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>ID</key>
    <string>B0A6EF3C-221F-4918-89C2-340B05F6A7AD</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>name</string>
    <key>Items</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>Mode</key>
        <integer>1000</integer>
        <key>background</key>
        <string>RGBA:0.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000</string>
        <key>Enabled</key>
        <true/>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>Mode</key>
        <integer>1000</integer>
        <key>background</key>
        <string>RGBA:0.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000</string>
        <key>Enabled</key>
        <true/>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

how can I search values for example if I want to get second `<dict>` item background and what about enable value that is true in this case
I want to do this in jquery

this is what i try so far

```
$.post("demo.xml",{},function(xml){
// Run the function for each dict tag inside array tag in the XML file
    $('array',xml).each(function(i) {
            $(this).find('dict').each(function(){

                $(this).find('key').each(function(){

                          key = $(this).text();
                          value = $(this).next().text();

                          alert("key = " + key + " value = "+ value);
                     }); 
             });

   });
```

the above jquery code work well for me but it return every key and its value .i want to search particular value out of it for example

```
var value = $(this).find("background").value;
```

i want to search by name such as "background"

Comment: show whatever you have tried

Comment: you refer this link;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220873/how-to-read-xml-file-contents-in-jquery-and-display-in-html-elements

Comment: the tag background has a value RGBA:0.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000. in our scenario

Answer (score 1):

Try something like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
type: "GET" ,
url: "file.xml" ,
dataType: "xml" ,
success: function(xml) { 
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find( "dict" ).each(function(){
           var data=$(this); //here we will get the data
       });
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: problem is not to read xml file .i just want to search value by its key name

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {
     $.get('myData.xml', function (d) {

```
     $(d).find('array').each(function () {

         var $array = $(this);

         var dict = $array.find('dict').each(function () {
             var key = dict.find('key').each(function () {
                 var value = $(this)
             })

         })
     })
 })
```

});

Comment: what you think what i get in value .this is same as my code but not working i need value by its key name that is inside dict tag. and thanks for your replay Ashish Yadav