# How to read an xml file using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I am currently working on getting datas from local xml file. But my code doesn't work. I have tried a lot of solutions but no one didn't work for me. The "data.xml" file is in the same folder with "index.html". I am using Chrome to test.

data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Names>
  <Name id="10" />
  <Name id="11" />
</Names>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
   <script src="Resources/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "data.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    $(xml).find('Name').each(function (element) {
                        var sTitle = $(element).attr('id');
                        alert(sTitle);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to read xml file contents in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220873/how-to-read-xml-file-contents-in-jquery-and-display-in-html-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Just change line `var sTitle = $(element).attr('id');` to:

```
var sTitle = $(this).attr('id');
```

This should solve your problem.

I noticed you are using an old and deprecated version of jquery. I advice you to use the latest version. Also you might consider using json rather then xml. It is simpler.