# How to extract city and state name from xml file using JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hello everyone I am trying to extract city and state name from the xml data, using google location api.

I am able to get the complete address from the xml data, the code which i have tried is as follow.

```
function get_add(latitude, longitude){
                $.get("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&sensor=false", function(data){

                        $(data).find("address_component").each(function(){
                                var unitData = $(this).find("long_name").text();
                                //var d = unitData.find("long_name").text();

                                $("#output").html("Latitude : " + latitude + "<br> Longitude: " + longitude + "<br>");
                                $("#output").append(unitData);
                                return false;
                        });     
                });
        }
```

I am passing latitude and longitude by own. The data that i am getting is complete address.

XML Format that i am getting is as follow(sample):

```
<GeocodeResponse>
     <status>OK</status>
     <address_component>
           <long_name>Bier</long_name>
           <short_name>Bier</short_name>
           <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
           <type>political</type>
     </address_component>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

I want to extract city and state name from the above.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: show your format how you getting address data

Comment: put this in your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read xml file contents in jQuery and display in html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220873/how-to-read-xml-file-contents-in-jquery-and-display-in-html-elements)

Comment: @AmitGaud:  http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=12.972442,77.580643&sensor=false

Comment: as suggested by @Alexander use that link to get your answer if still get problem you can sure ask more

Comment: Thank you guys,  I am able to get the complete address format from xml but not able to extract the city and state name instead of that whole address.

Comment: @AmitGaud I have tried the method that suggested by Alexander, still it is getting the full address but not able to get the specific data.