# Jquery - how to get contents of data that contains '#document' from a $.get scrape?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I am stuck because I get an 'unidentified character error' at the '#' .  I have included the site I am trying to scrape, and i get the variable back 'data' that when I print to console has a full list of information, however when i try to access those nodes I can't because of the '#' it seems.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.get(
            "https://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=generic",
            function(data) {


            console.log(data);

            }
         )  
});
```

how can i extract the contents of data which contains '#document'

Comment: Did you try `data['#document']` ?

Comment: yes @James and thank you it gives me undefined

Comment: It looks like the page you're loading returns a XML document rather than a JSON document.  So, "data" should be the root node, and you should iterate it using XML-friendly functions rather than object-style.  Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220873/how-to-read-xml-file-contents-in-jquery-and-display-in-html-elements)