# get XML Elements Value to HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rss xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>title of XML</title>
        <description>description of XML</description>
        <ttl>720</ttl>
        <item>
            <title>title_01</title>
            <description>value of item 01</description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>title_02</title>
            <description>value of item 02</description>
        </item>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <item>
            <title>title_XX</title>
            <description>value of item XX</description>
        </item>


    </channel>
</rss>
```

And I need to get value from elements to HTML elements. From the element ITEM where the TITLE has the specific unique value put the DESCRIPTION value to the HTML element:

```
<body>
    <div class="cont">

    <div>
    <span id="some_id01">Here put the DESCRIPTION value from the XML ITEM which contains the specific TITLE value</span>
    <span id="some_id02"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
    <span id="some_id03"></span>
    <span id="some_id04"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
    <span id="some_idXX"></span>
        </div>

    </div>

    </body>
```

[Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220873/how-to-read-xml-file-contents-in-jquery-and-display-in-html-elements?answertab=votes#tab-top). But there are no loops, just fixed number of HTML elements. Could anyone help me the optimal code, there can be up to 100 ITEM element in XML.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you specify whether you are using your XML as a database for an online service or whether this is some sort of offline exercise? In the former, we'd need to know what server-side language you are using. In the latter case, an XQuery transformation is probably what you want.

Comment: Hi, XML is placed on web server. e.g. http://4ds.online/bs/bistroreal/pondelitest.xml There is no database - it is uploading manually via FTP. Can use php, jqeury...

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea to refer, hope that helps:

```
const getElement = (id) => {
  return document.getElementById(id) || null;
};

const getIdByTitle = (title) => {
  return title.split('_')[1];
};

const load = (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = () => {
      return resolve(xhr.responseXML.documentElement);
    }
    xhr.onerror = () => {
      return reject(new Error('Error while getting XML.'));
    }
    xhr.open('GET', file);
    xhr.responseType = "document";
    xhr.send();
  });
}

const process = (xml) => {
  let nodes = Array.from(xml.getElementsByTagName('item'));
  return nodes.map((node) => {
    let title = node.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;
    let description = node.getElementsByTagName('description')[0].innerHTML;
    let id = getIdByTitle(title);
    return {
      id,
      title,
      description,
    }
  });
};

const display = (items) => {
  return items.map((item) => {
    let {
      id,
      description,
    } = item;

    let el = getElement(`some_id${id}`);
    if (el) {
      el.innerHTML = description;
    }
  });
};

load('relative_path_to_XML_file.xml')
  .then(process)
  .then(display)
  .catch(console.trace);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems this works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //feed to parse
    var feed = "pondelitest.xml";

    $.ajax(feed, {
        accepts:{
            xml:"application/rss+xml"
        },
        dataType:"xml",
        success:function(data) {



            $(data).find("title").each(function () { 
                if($(this).text() == 'jidlo01' ) {
                        var v01 = $(this).next();
                        $("#jidlo01").append($.trim(v01.text()));
                        }
                if($(this).text() == 'jidlo02' ) {
                        var v01 = $(this).next();
                        $("#jidlo02").append($.trim(v01.text()));
                        }                       
            });
        // remove empty items
        $('span.title').each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':empty')) $(this).parent().remove();
});

        }  
    });

});
```