# Transmit data from PHP5.3 to JS without using json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, validation, encode

**Context :** I work for a company using mainly PHP5.3.29 and even if the transition to 7.2 is scheduled, it's not going to happen tomorrow.
json_encode, jsondecode and curl functions are disabled (A hook prevents committing code containing such functions).

**Problem :** I'm trying to send data as an http response and so far I've tried to :

- Send back urlencoded data
- Send back base64'd data

But the thing is I've got encoding issues in the JS section, receiving unwanted '+' characters or bad entity encoding.

**Quesion :** Did anyone had to deal with such constraints and how is it possible to get around ? Could someone explain to me what are behaviours behind these functions ? I'm having a hard time understanding these problems. Thanks in advance.

**Edit :** [Encoding problem using base64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg25I.png)

[Based on JaromandaX's answers and using *base64_encode (utf8_encode ($item))*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plKbU.png)

Comment: have you tried so called *url base64* it replaces `+`,`/` with `-`, `_` and totally removes `=` (because the number of `=` can be calculated)

Comment: Is there a particular reason that the json functions are disabled?

Comment: You could use XML in a pinch, assuming the data you wish to return is readily structured as such. Libraries like jQuery can parse XML.

Comment: @JaromandaX : Still got an encoding problem (Adding screen to the main question).

Comment: @CaptainSquirrel : Only cryptic info about such functions unavailable on our techbase.

Comment: @Darragh Enright : No jQuery but i could still try to do it using XML, I'm going to give it a try and update the post.

Comment: If so, this might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220873/how-to-read-xml-file-contents-in-jquery-and-display-in-html-elements

Comment: If you need to do this in raw JS then [MDN's document on parsing/serializing XML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML) might be useful reading

Comment: Re encoding problem, clearly not base64 encoded - but I can't see HOW you created that problem - what with no actual code

Comment: @JaromandaX : Well, I used base64_encode ($item) in PHP and atob (item) in JS. Shouldn't it be that way ? (Sorry, maybe a rookie question)

Comment: Oh, I see, so that picture is the "decoded" data, and that's coming out bad - I see now - what does the original data look like? is it binary? string? what character encoding is the string?

Comment: The left display is whatI need to get, the right one is what I'm trying to display through JS

Comment: Oh, right ... sorry ... didn't notice that :p `base64_encode(utf8_encode($str))`? or perhaps http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: Didn't do the trick... (Cf. link in main post)
Can't use mb_functions either ^^" (Yes, complicated and buggy framework)