# Is it possible to add an .XML file in Chrome Extension to store/retrieve data?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I have built a Chrome Extension for my Office and at some points, i need to store/retrieve basic data and I thought of having a simple `XML` file in the same folder with the `manifest` and `js` files.

**Something like:**

```
 <templates>
       <template>
          <title> Invoice sent</title>
          <text>

            Dear [CUSTOMER_NAME],
            We have just issued you an invoice.
            Kindly note that the total amount does not include the Pre-export 
            inspection fee.

            **Please get back to us soonest possible, so we can reserve the 
            [PRODUCT_NAME] for you and avoid having it
            sold to a different client.

            Regards
            [STAFF_NAME]
            [DEPARTMENT_NAME]

    </text>
      </template>

      <template>
          <title>........

</templates>
```

The `<templates>` *tag* will have multiple `<template>` *tags* which will contain different `<title>` and `<text>` *tags*.

The *[CONTENTS IN BRACKETS]* should be dynamically changed when the `XML` is read by `javascript` .

1. How does my `.js` file access the `XML` file? (any sample `code` will be highly appreciated)
2. How to add the `XML` file to the `manifest.json` file so as to be accessible by the `content002.js` file?

so far the `manifest.json` looks something like:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "myExtName",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "My Browser extension",

  "content_scripts": [{
    //"css": ["styles.css"],
    "js": ["content002.js","jquery.js"],
    "matches": ["https://www.companysite.com/*","file://*"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }]

}
```

**I have tried:** [How to read xml file contents in jQuery and display in html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220873/how-to-read-xml-file-contents-in-jquery-and-display-in-html-elements)

But No success so far, apparently the using:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET" ,
        url: "xmlFile.xml" ,
        dataType: "xml" ,
```

returns an error indicating that the `$.ajax` is looking for the `xmlFile` in the *remote server* , but NOT in the *Chrome extension* root folder

Comment: you can use `<template>` tags in `HTML`, while it's unlikely you would store data to an `XML` file.

Comment: You can have any data you want in your extension package. All you need is to either expose that file via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) so it becomes visible to the web pages including your content script or 2) read it in a background script and transfer the data to the content script via messaging or chrome.storage.local. Note that an extension can't change any files inside its installed package.

Comment: any sample code will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @wOxxOm how does the `.js` access the `.xml` to *Write* and *Read* `nodes`? is via `$.ajax GET` or how?... any sample `code` is very highly appreciated

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the references... `Read/write` is no issue at all but accessing the file is what seems to be a mountainous task.. the resource you sent doesnt clarify how the `.js` file will access the files under the `chrome-extension://[PACKAGE ID]/[PATH] ` should it be: `$.ajax({ type: "GET" , url: "chrome-extension://[PACKAGE ID]/xmlFile.xml" ` or? ,  still trying

Comment: The documentation says you need to declare the file in "web_accessible_resources" in manifest.json and then access it using chrome.runtime.getURL. If you don't like the documentation you can easily find examples by googling this keyword.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the references... So far it's promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while but finally it worked.

Here is what I did.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "EXTENSION NAME",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "DESCRIPTION GOES HERE",

  "content_scripts": [{

    "js": ["jq3.js","JAVASCRIPT.js"],
    "matches": ["https://*/*","file://*"],
    "run_at": "document_end"

  }],

  "web_accessible_resources": 
      ["xmlFile.xml"] //This .xml file is in the same directory with the manifest    
  }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var xmlCont = chrome.runtime.getURL("xmlFile.xml"); //this returns the FULL_PATH of the .xml file [NOT THE XML NODES]
            console.log(xmlCont) //You can see it here

                    $.ajax({                    
                          type: "GET" , 
                          url: xmlCont,//Place that FULL_PATH here 
                          dataType: "xml" , //This too is important 

                         success: function(xml) { 

                          console.log(xml)// see the ajax results if your curious

                        //var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );//NOT NEED FOR THIS

                        //console.log(xmlDoc);// if you parseXML it returns null

                        var title = $(xml).find('value').text(); //Show the text between the <title> tags
                        console.log(title);

                    }    
                        });
```

**XML**

```
<rss version='2.0'>
    <channel>
        <title>
I am the text between the -title- tag
       </title>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Hope it helps someone